# TextField in MenuItem - onKeyDown event interfering with onChange in TextField

Tags: material-ui

I'm am trying to put a TextField in a Menu. It works for the most part except if the text field is empty and i press the "d" key instead of firing the onChange event it skips to the next MenuItem in the list.

I tried giving the Menu an onKeyDown event and calling event.stopPropagation() and preventDefault but I think its on the MenuList not the Menu.

```js
function UserRequests(props) {
    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null)
    const [filter, setFilter] = useState('')

    const handleClick = e => setAnchorEl(e.currentTarget)
    const handleClose = () => setAnchorEl(null)

    const filteredUsers = props.pending.filter(x =>
        x.user.name.includes(filter)
    )

    const handleFilterChange = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        e.stopPropagation()
        setFilter(e.target.value)
    }

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Badge
                color="secondary"
                badgeContent={props.pending.length}
                invisible={props.pending.length < 1}
            >
                <Button
                    aria-controls="simple-menu"
                    aria-haspopup="true"
                    onClick={handleClick}
                    variant="outlined"
                    color="primary"
                    className={props.classes.button}
                >
                    Pending Requests
                </Button>
            </Badge>
            <Menu
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                keepMounted
                open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
                onClose={handleClose}
            >
                <MenuItem button={false}>
                    <TextField
                        label="Filter"
                        value={filter}
                        fullWidth
                        onChange={handleFilterChange}
                    />
                </MenuItem>
                {props.pending.length > 0 ? (
                    filteredMemebers.map(({ id, user }) => (
                        <MenuItem key={id} button={false}>
                            {user.name}
                            <ApproveUserButton
                                id={id}
                                domain={props.domain}
                            />
                            <RemoveUserButton
                                id={id}
                                domain={props.domain}
                            />
                        </MenuItem>
                    ))
                ) : (
                    <MenuItem button={false}>No Pending Users</MenuItem>
                )}
            </Menu>
        </Fragment>
    )
}
```

Expected Result: I type in the textbox and it handles normaly

Actual: When i type in the textbox some key presses are being used by other handlers before they hit my handleFilterChange

Answer (score 4):

You're on the right track with stopping propagation of the `onKeyDown` event, but in this case you need to stop propagation from the `TextField` component itself, rather than from the `Menu` component.

The example below demonstrates this. The `stopPropagation` method contains some extra checks to avoid disabling keyboard focus navigation in the menu. Also the `onKeyDown` on the TextField's `MenuItem` allows using <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> to move focus into the input for typing.

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Menu from "@material-ui/core/Menu";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

export default function SimpleMenu() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const [filter, setFilter] = React.useState("");
  const filterRef = React.useRef();
  function handleClick(event) {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  }

  function handleClose() {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  }
  const stopPropagation = e => {
    switch (e.key) {
      case "ArrowDown":
      case "ArrowUp":
      case "Home":
      case "End":
        break;
      default:
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
  };
  const moveFocusToInput = e => {
    if (e.key === "Tab" || e.key === "ArrowRight") {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      filterRef.current.focus();
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        aria-controls="simple-menu"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Open Menu
      </Button>
      <Menu
        id="simple-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <MenuItem button={false} onKeyDown={moveFocusToInput}>
          <TextField
            inputRef={filterRef}
            label="Filter"
            value={filter}
            onKeyDown={stopPropagation}
            onChange={e => setFilter(e.target.value)}
          />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit TextField in MenuItem]

Note that you don't want to call `preventDefault` on the `onKeyDown` event of the `TextField`, since that will prevent the `onChange` event from firing.