# I want to disable keyboard input for this date picker how to do that?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, material-ui

please check this link and tell me which props or event should I use for this....

https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-frost-qrvwe?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

use `inputProps` property .

```
<TextField
        id="date"
        label="Birthday"
        type="month"
        defaultValue="2017-05"
        className={classes.textField}
        InputLabelProps={{
          shrink: true,
        
        }}
        InputProps={{
          readOnly: true,
         }}
      />
```

Comment: Through this my calendar option getting disabled. user can change month year using the mouse I want to restrict from the keyboard.

Comment: maybe this link will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56995208/textfield-in-menuitem-onkeydown-event-interfering-with-onchange-in-textfield

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Fixed it by customizing input to button.

```html
() => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  const ExampleCustomInput = forwardRef(({ value, onClick }, ref) => (
    <button className="example-custom-input" onClick={onClick} ref={ref}>
      {value}
    </button>
  ));
  return (
    <DatePicker
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
      customInput={<ExampleCustomInput />}
    />
  );
};
```

https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-disable-keyboard-navigation example "Custom input"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34253097)